# Youtube iframe api. Player state gets stuck on BUFFERING state on mobile devices

Tags: api, iframe, youtube

For my app I need to constantly monitor the state of the youtube player but for some reason **onStateChange** behaves differently on desktop and mobile. In particular I have the following problem: when I try to change the current time of the player to the point that is not buffered yet and the player is currently in PAUSED state, it switches to the **BUFFERING** state and never goes back to **PAUSED** state even after it finishes buffering. On the desktop it switches to **BUFFERING** and then back to PAUSED which is exactly what I want.

I use custom loading overlay when the player is buffering so this behavior complete breaks the functionality. The overlay just gets stuck on mobile devices forever.

If anyone experienced similar issues please let me know.

Thanks.